# Setting returned text to open an app in applescript

Tags: ios, applescript, osx-mavericks

I have a apple script program that I am programming and I want the text the user sends to open an application, But I keep getting error messages saying "Can't get application {"name_of_app"} of <>. The code I very simple and I cant figure out the problem

```
set deReturnedItems to (display dialog "How many spam messages?" with icon stop default                         answer "" buttons {"Quit", "OK"} default button 2)
set xpp to text returned of deReturnedItems
set theReturnedItems to (display dialog "How many spam messages?" with icon stop default   answer "" buttons {"Quit", "OK"} default button 2)
set amt to the text returned of theReturnedItems
set daReturnedItems to (display dialog "Last thing, what should the spam message say?"  default answer "" buttons {"Quit", "OK"} default button 2)
set msg to the text returned of daReturnedItems
repeat [amt] times
    tell application [xpp]
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke [msg]
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of those square brackets. Don't use them for variables. Use underscores before and after if you must, like:

```
repeat _amt_ times
    …
end
```

Also, you need to check to make sure your variable is an integer before you use it in the repeat block.

Incidentally, when you set a variable and then include it in brackets, that's applescript syntax for set the string to a list. For example:

```
set [x, y, z] to "123"
return x
-- returns "1", and y is set to "2", and z is set to "3"
```